# C# list of object and reference the object in the list

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a question concerning reference of an object in a list.

I have a Students Class as below

```
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Students> ListOfStudents = new List<Students>();
        ListOfStudents.Add(new Students("Alex", 1));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new Students("Bob", 2));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new Students("Cathrine", 3));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new Students("Dave", 4));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new Students("Eric", 5));
        ListOfStudents.Add(new Students("Frank", 6));

        foreach (var student in ListOfStudents)
        {
            Students s = new Students(student.StudentName, student.StudentID);
            s.Dosomework();
        }
    }


    public class Students
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }

        public Students()
        { }
        public Students(string _studentname, int _studentid)
        {
            StudentName = _studentname;
            StudentID = _studentid;

        }
        Timer timerDoSomethingEveryTsec = new Timer();
        public void Dosomework()
        {
            InitTimerEveryTsec(5000);
        }
        public void StopWork()
        {
            timerDoSomethingEveryTsec.Stop();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This is the timer for the action after x time
        /// </summary>
        public void InitTimerEveryTsec(int t)
        {
            timerDoSomethingEveryTsec.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_TickEveryTsec);
            timerDoSomethingEveryTsec.Interval = t; // in miliseconds
            timerDoSomethingEveryTsec.Start();
        }
        private void timer1_TickEveryTsec(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(StudentName + " is working with ID " + StudentID);
        }
    }
```

And a ListOfStudents.

Now, if when i load my form, the students class will "Dosomework" every tick.
My question is:

How do I access the very specific instantiated "Students s" where s = Eric with the ID = 5.

I want to access the student "ERIC with #5" to s.Stop().  Is there away to achieve that?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since none of the instances of `Students` in your list is actually running the `Dosomework` method, it's going to be quite hard to stop Eric.

The reason for that is that instead of calling the `Dosomework` method for the instances in your list, **you are creating new instances** with the same properties and call the `Dosomework` method on these instances. This means that by the time your `foreach` loop ends, `s` will point to a new instance of the `Students` class with the name `Frank` and id `6`, and you have no reference to the instance of `Eric` that is actually doing some work.

So the first thing to change is the code inside the `foreach` loop - Instead of creating new instances, you should simply execute the `Dosomework` method on the instances stored in the list:

```
    foreach (var student in ListOfStudents)
    {
        student.Dosomework();
    }
```

Then you can use the [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find the student with id = 5:

```
var eric = ListOfStudents.Find(s => s.Id == 5);
```

Now that you've got the correct instance, all you need to do is execute the `StopWork` method:

```
eric.StopWork();
```

Also, I would recommend sticking to [c# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) - use Pascal casing for all your methods (so `Dosomework` becomes `DoSomeWork`)

Comment: Thank you,  var eric = ListOfStudents.Find(s => s.Id == 5); did point me to the correct point.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyStudent = ListOfStudents.Where(x=> x.ID == 5).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You should consider posting some explanation about what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have...

```
List<Students> listOfStudents = new List<Students>();
```

Then you could find a student with...

```
var eric = listOfStudents.Where(x => x.StudentName=="Eric" && x.StudentID==5).FirstOfDefault(null);
```

BTW, I'd really recommend calling your class "Student" since each instance represents a single student.  This also allows the list variable to be "students" since it represents one or more students.

Comment: [`FirstOfDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor doesn't expect any parameters.

Comment: No need to use `.Where` or `.FirstOrDefault`.  Both of those imply that there are multiple students with the name Eric and an Id of 5.  There could be many students with the same name, but the Id makes them unique.    `listOfStudents.Single(x => x.StudentID==5);`

Comment: Nice tip.  Often learn things myself answering questions.  :)